# Def Function with for loop giving error as "object of type 'int' has no len()", 'occurred at index 0'

Tags: python, dataframe

```
a = pd.DataFrame({"A":['a', 'a','b','c','a','b','c','b','c','c'],
                  "C":[0.4,0.38,0.42,0.85,0.22,0.38,0.38,0.11,0.21,0.21]})

a['B'] = a.groupby("A").cumcount()+1
a = a.sort_values(by=['A','B'])
a = a.reset_index()
a['D'] = pd.DataFrame(round(a.groupby('A')['C'].cumsum(),2))
a['E'] =""
a['F'] =""
a['J'] =""

for i in range(len(a.B)):
        if a.B[i]<=1:
            if a.D[i] <1:
                a.E[i] = 'No'
            else:
                a.E[i] = 'Yes'
        else:
            if a.D[i-1]>=1:
                a.E[i]='NA'
            else:
                if a.D[i]<1:
                    a.E[i]='No'
                else:
                    a.E[i]='Yes'
i=i+1
```

I defined the above loop in a function but I got an error as "object of type 'int' has no len()", 'occurred at index 0'

```
def five(x,y,z):
for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i]<=1:
        if y[i]<1:
            z[i]='No'
        else:
            z[i]='Yes'
    else:
        if y[(i-1)]>=1:
            z[i]='N/A'
        else:
            if y[i]<1:
                z[i]='No'
            else:
                z[i]='Yes'
```

a['E'] = a.apply(lambda row: five(row['B'],row['D'],row['E']), axis=1)

Comment: `range(len(x))` Apparently `x` is a single integer, which means somewhere you're calling `five()` with a single integer as the first argument.

Comment: is there a correct way of doing this?

Comment: Is `row['B']` sometimes a single integer, and sometimes a list?  Or is it always a single?

Comment: `a['B'] = a.groupby("A").cumcount()+1` It looks like `a['B']` is always a single integer.  So why are you trying to call `len()` on it?

Comment: Hi John, column B is a countif column for column A in a dataset. However, if range(len(a.B) is giving proper value, then why not in the function?

Comment: Is `a.B` the same as `a['B']`?

Comment: yes John, a.B is same as a['B'].

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `lambda` within `apply` with `axis=1`, each row is passed to the function. So in your case `five(...)` gets a single row, so `x` which is `row['B']` is essentially an `integer` instead of a `list`.

Refer [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/apply-and-lambda-usage-in-pandas-b13a1ea037f7) for the usage of `apply` with `lambda`.

Comment: Hi, Are you saying that I am applying Lambda incorrectly. If yes, can you suggest the correct way?

Comment: Can you tell me more about the output you would want?

Comment: if you execute codes in the first part of my question, the output you get is something I am looking for but want to put it in a function so that I can apply it on multiple columns without writing the same loops again